# Sequelize syntax Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a simple setup for Sequelize.

```
var config = require('../config'),
    Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
    sequelize = new Sequelize(
        config.get('database'),
        config.get('username'),
        config.get('password'), {
            host: config.get('host'),
            port: config.get('dbport'),
            dialect: config.get('dialect'),
            pool: {
                max: 5,
                min: 0,
                idle: 10000
            }
        })
```

If i run an ordinary check `sequelize.authenticate()` it works fine and shows that there are no problems with connection. But if i try to define a simple model, `sequelize.sync();` throws an error: `Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax error at or near "NOT"`.
It seems to me that there is a problem within sequelize or a driver.
BTW I use PostgreSQL 9.0.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those, who'll be experiencing the same problem.

As stated in the [Syntax error on `sequelize.define()`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5015) issue Alex created, this is related to what PostgreSQL version is `sequelize` connecting to:

> Postgres 9.0 (and, of course, older) does not support CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS

---

Two different solutions to the problem:

- upgrade PostgreSQL version itself (9.4 is the latest stable)
- upgrade `sequelize` to the latest version ([the fix](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/commit/3774bebbbfecbf008dc500f94b24105a8a252078) was applied to [`sequelize` 3.15](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/releases/tag/v3.15.0))